# Collapse/uncollapse a Tree in Godot 4 by clicking on the TreeItem?

Tags: gui, godot, godot-4

Is there a way to collapse/uncollapse a [`Tree`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tree.html) (Control) in Godot 4 by clicking on the [`TreeItem`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_treeitem.html) instead of the folding arrow?

I mean, I click on an item, gets selected and the subitems get uncollapsed. Click again the same item and the subitems get collapsed.

I've managed to achieve a similar behaviour by connecting the [`item_selected()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tree.html#signals) signal from the `Tree`, but it just doesn't work flawlessly:

- Some mouse clicks are missed if you click quick (less quick than a double-click though).
- The selected item must be deselected because **the signal won't trigger again if the item is already selected**, and I'd like the item to be shown as selected.

Here's the code:

```
@onready var characters_tree: Tree = $MarginContainer/Tree

func _on_tree_item_selected() -> void:
    var item := characters_tree.get_selected()
    item.collapsed = not item.collapsed
    item.deselect(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the Tree's `item_mouse_selected` signal, which is emitted when an item is selected with a mouse button. It is even emitted again if the item is already selected, so you don't have to deselect it in your code.

```
func _on_tree_item_mouse_selected(position, mouse_button_index):
    var item = characters_tree.get_selected()
    item.collapsed = not item.collapsed
```

However, if you click twice fast enough to be considered a double-click, this signal is not emitted for the second click. Instead the `item_activated` signal is emitted. You mentioned that your quick clicks were less quick than a double-click, but double-clicks can be deceptively long and still register as one. To account for this, you should also connect to the `item_activated` signal.

```
func _on_tree_item_activated():
    var item = characters_tree.get_selected()
    item.collapsed = not item.collapsed
```